# How to use testInput create a list, and assign the list names as the same textInput in R shiny?

Tags: r, list, shiny

I want to create a list based on users' input via `textInput`, and the assign the list names with the same textInput.

For instance, if the user's input is `a`, then the list name is `a`, the element is `paste0(a, Sys.Data())`.

below is my example. I can create the list, but I don't know how to assign the list names.

```r
library(shiny)

my_list <- reactiveVal(list())

ui <- fluidPage(
  textInput(inputId = "my_input", label = "Enter some text:"),
  actionButton(inputId = "add_button", label = "Add"),
  verbatimTextOutput(outputId = "my_output")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  observeEvent(input$add_button, {
    new_item <- isolate(input$my_input)
    if (nchar(new_item) > 0) {
      my_list(append(my_list(), list(paste0(new_item, Sys.Date()))))
    }
  })
  
  output$my_output <- renderPrint({
    my_list()
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `setNames` like so:

```
library(shiny)

my_list <- reactiveVal(list())

ui <- fluidPage(
  textInput(inputId = "my_input", label = "Enter some text:"),
  actionButton(inputId = "add_button", label = "Add"),
  verbatimTextOutput(outputId = "my_output")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$add_button, {
    new_item <- isolate(input$my_input)
    if (nchar(new_item) > 0) {
      my_list(append(my_list(), setNames(list(paste0(new_item, Sys.Date())), new_item)))
    }
  })

  output$my_output <- renderPrint({
    my_list()
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]